# Inserting images into JSX using a function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jsx, src

I've got a problem inserting an img into JSX img tag. I have a function getImg() that returns an img path relatively a component.
I call this function in the src attribute of the tag like this:

`<img src={getImg(currentWeather.conditionId)} alt="weather condition" className={s.cw__icon} />`

The path is being inserted into DOM. [DOM path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6OjR.png)

I checked this path is absolutely correct, you can see it yourself, here's my project structure. [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHhim.png)

I tried to import a single img using this path and insert it as a variable, it worked perfectly fine.

As I understand, there's no way to get an img by inserting a string path into JSX. I tried that require thing, but it didn't work for me, if I wrap it around my function. it returns this error. [Error using require with function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IsYy.png)

`<img src={(require(getImg(currentWeather.conditionId)))} alt="weather condition" className={s.cw__icon} />`

But if I hardcode the path that my function returns, then everything works. Makes me think that sth is wrong with the function...

```
export const getImg = (key) => {
    let imgSrc;
    switch (findByKey(key, weatherConditions)) {

        case 'rainy':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/rain.png';
            break;
        case 'snowy':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/snow.png';
            break;
        case 'sunny':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/sun.png';
            break;
        case 'partlyCloudy':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/partly-cloudy.png';
            break;
        case 'cloudy':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/clouds.png';
            break;
        case 'foggy':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/fog.png';
            break;
        case 'storm':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/storm.png';
            break;
        case 'thunder':
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/thunder.png';
            break;
        default:
            imgSrc = '../../assets/img/weather-news.png';
            break;
    }

    return imgSrc;
}
```

Comment: If the path returned by your function is correct **from the client-side perspective**, that will work. Remember, it's the browser that reads that string and builds the absolute URL from the page location with that relative path applied. If it doesn't work, the path isn't correct. There's nothing special about the `src` attribute that would make filling it in from a function's return value difficult or different from any other.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: If I copy this path and paste it inside the require function, it works. Which means the path should be correct. Unless there're some other rules...

Comment: This is the text of the error:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/img/clouds.png'
    at webpackEmptyContext (CurrentWeather|sync:2:1)
    at CurrentWeather (CurrentWeather.jsx:37:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)

Comment: at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)

Comment: To improve your question, please use the "edit" link on the question, rather than comments. But again, there aren't hidden gotchas here: The path that ends up in the `src` attribute is incorrect if the image isn't being displayed. You just have to debug why that is. (That's with your current approach; the `require` approach has completely different rules, the `require` path is relative to the module you're doing the `require` in.)